# Python np.arange weird behavior

Tags: python, numpy

The `np.arange` function is behaving weird in my code. 24 is my increment and in this example, it prints "ortalama" 24 times. Why would this happen?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
i=0
j=0
k=0
array=np.zeros((100000, 4))
sums=np.zeros(100000)

consumer = KafkaConsumer('005', group_id='my-group',bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])

for message in consumer:
    a=message.value
    a=a.decode("utf-8") 
    a = a.split(',')
    for j in range(0,4):
        array[i,j]=a[j]     
    #print(array)
    if i%60==0 and i>60:        
        b= array[i-60:i,3] 
        total=np.sum(b)
        sums[k]=total
        k=k+1
        l=np.arange(0, k, 24)       
        ortalama=np.mean(sums[l])
        print(ortalama)
        if ortalama>=219000:
            print("1")
    i=i+1
```

Comment: Post you code in here it's much easier for us to see and manipulate and you won't get your question downvoted

Comment: And it would be helpful if you can create a [mcve]

Comment: Clicking on the link opens the picture. I could not load the photo inside the post. If someone could help me, please do that.

Comment: Add your code as raw code, just copy paste it and write your question below. Add the `code` format to it and if you don't know how just copy paste it raw and someone will edit it. But all these options are better than a hyperlink picture that we can't do anything about.

Comment: Paste your code as text in the question, no images unless images are relevant to the question. Also post what you got and what you expected to see.

Comment: Please see the updated question.

Comment: what is the value of `k` at the end of the run?

Comment: I believe your question title is misleading: `np.arange` is not the source of your issue, but everything around it.

Comment: The value of k is 691.

Comment: @LucaCappelletti, I think the opposite. If I change 24 to 10, it prints the value of `ortalama` 10 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code refactoring

To understand what is wrong with this code first of all we proceed with refactoring:

#### A class to simulate the expected messages

Customise this class as need to simulate an average message from your Kafka.

```
class Message:
    """Class to simulate expected Kafka message."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = "10,20,30,40".encode()
```

#### A random message generator

Customise this generator to simulate a plausible message from Kafka.

```
import random
import time

def message_generator(n):
    """Yield a generated Kafka message."""
    for i in range(n):
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0, 0.001))
        yield Message()
```

#### Refactored code

Before proceeding to any code dissection, let's refactor this code a bit, using numpy's `vstack` and `append` to extend the arrays, other than defining some constants. I also have renamed `array` to `my_array`.

```
import numpy as np
my_array, sums = np.empty((0, 4)), np.empty((1))
STEP = 60
MESSAGES = 100000   
MAX_MEAN = 219000 

for i, message in enumerate(message_generator(MESSAGES)):
    values = np.array(message.value.decode("utf-8").split(',')).astype(float)
    my_array = np.vstack([my_array, values])
    if i % STEP == 0 and i > STEP:
        sums = np.append(sums, np.sum(my_array[i - STEP:i, 3]))
        l = np.arange(0, len(sums), 24)
        if np.mean(sums[l]) >= MAX_MEAN:
            print("Large ortalama")
```

### Code dissecting

#### Debunking your claim that any issue is from `np.arange`

Now, your code creates a list `l` of values, from `0` to `len(sums)`, with a step `24`. There is nothing wrong with `np.arange`.

#### What your code does

You have an array `sums`, to which you add every 60 iterations the sum of the last 60 iterations of the third column of your array `my_array`.

Then you proceed to generating `l` and then create a mean from the values of `sums` with the indices from `l`. **This is dependant only on the messages you receive.**

When such mean is larger or equal to a given `MAX_MEAN`, you print a message.

### Replicating the core

Let's suppose that the sum of every window is a constant `constant_sum`. We call the set of these constants `elements`. Clearly, your mean `ortalama` value is equal to `constant_sum`.

As you can see, `elements_step` is **simplified** from the function and is considered only in function of the input messages.

```
elements = np.array([])
elements_step = 5
constant_sum = 1000
upper_limit = 10000
for i in range(1000):
    elements = np.append(elements, constant_sum)
    l = np.arange(0, len(elements), elements_step)
    ortalama = np.mean(elements[l])
    if ortalama >= upper_limit:
        print("Large ortalama")
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanations. What puzzles me is that, the values of `ortalama` are printed exactly as many times as increment of `np.arange` function.

Comment: I have added an explanation of why ortolama is dependant only on the messages, demonstrating how with constant messages the `np.arange` parameter is simplified completely.